Spring boot 3 - Missing trace view , How to troubleshoot?
I have a simple spring boot 3.2.x based applications ( github links below).
My steps are from this documentation - https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3
Note: I did not use class MyConfiguration given in the example. (assuming that it is not impacting trace view issue)
Traceid is propogating, so that looks ok from logs ( as seen in screenshot)
I would like to know how to troubleshoot - Trace View

Client: https://github.com/kswat/customer-service
Service1 : https://github.com/kswat/contact-service
Service 2 : https://github.com/kswat/vehicle-service
Used docker folder from here  ( including docker-compose to spin tempo , prometheus)
https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/observability-boot-blog-post/tree/main
Usage: spin the 3 services and call
http://localhost:9080/customer/501
Note: I don't know anything about the yamls and json inside docker folder.
How to identify the root cause and get the trace view
Edit:
I now understand that I am missing some important details like this below
    @Observed(name = "user.name",
    contextualName = "getting-user-name",
    lowCardinalityKeyValues = {"userType", "userType2"})

my service does not have user type. How to determine lowCardinalityKeyValues in my project ?
(will have to commit code similar to MyHandler)
Edit 2:
I have run the spring example as-is (including otlp branch - https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/observability-boot-blog-post/tree/otlp ) , still don't see trace view. Not sure if I need to click Tempo button on logs with trace id.


I updated "queryType": "traceql", (from traceId) and it seems working

but I don't think this is correct. so looking for a fix
